# Randomizing list of words with Python

Tags: python

I need help with solving a problem. I have list of 8 words.

What I need to achieve is to generate all possible variants where exactly 3 of this words are included. All those variants need to be saved in different .txt file. The same words but in different positions should be treated as another variant.

It needs to be done on Raspberry Pi in Python.

To be honest i don't even know where to start with it...

I am total noob in any sort of programming...

Any clues how to do it?

Comment: Start by learning basic python, data structures etc., then find the `itertools` module

Comment: Specifically, `itertools.permutations`

Answer (score 7):

You can easily solve this problem by using `itertools`. In the following example, I will produce all possible combinations of 3 elements for the list `l`:

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> list(itertools.permutations(l, 3))

[(1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 4),
 (1, 2, 5),
 (1, 3, 4),
 (1, 3, 5),
 (1, 4, 5),
 ...
 ...
 (2, 3, 4),
 (2, 3, 5),
 (2, 4, 5),
 (3, 4, 5),
 ...
 ...
 (5, 4, 2),
 (5, 4, 3)]
```

Now, if you want to save those values in a different text file, you should do the following:

```
for i, e in enumerate(itertools.permutations(l, 3)):
    with open(f"file_{i}.txt","w+") as f:
        f.write(e)
```

Comment: OP wants that *The same words but in different positions should be treated as another variant.*, so `permutations` is the right one to use instead of `combinations`

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Could you please help me out how change the code to save every combination to a different text file? File name can generated randomly...

Comment: @4k3or3et, I updated my answer, if that was useful for you, I would appreciate you upvote/validate it.

Comment: I just tried your method. i get:

  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    for i, e in itertools.permutations(l, 3):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 2):

@lmiguelvargasf's answer only covers half the question, so here comes the part where you save the word combinations to individual files.

```
import itertools
import random
import string

class fileNames:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file_names = []

    def randomString(self,stringLength):
        letters = string.ascii_lowercase
        file_name = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))
        if file_name in self.file_names:
            randomString(stringLength)
        self.file_names.append(file_name)
        return file_name

# Original word list 
l = [1, 2, 3]
# Create a new list, containing the combinations
word_combinations = list(itertools.permutations(l, 3))

# Creating an instance of fileNames() class
files = fileNames()

# Specifying the number of characters
n = 5

# For each of these combinations, save in a file
for word_comb in word_combinations:
    # The file will be named by a random string containing n characters
    with open('{}.txt'.format(files.randomString(n)), 'w') as f:
            # The file will contain each word seperated by a space, change the string below as desired
            f.write('{} {} {}'.format(word_comb[0], word_comb[1], word_comb[2]))
```

If you want the filename to be an integer which increases with 1 for every file, do swap the last part with this:

```
# For each of these combinations, save in a file
for n, word_comb in enumerate(word_combinations):
    # The file will be named by an integer
    with open('{}.txt'.format(n), 'w') as f:
            # The file will contain each word seperated by a space, change the string below as desired
            f.write('{} {} {}'.format(word_comb[0], word_comb[1], word_comb[2]))
```

Comment: Cool stuff. How to do a filename which would increase +1 in number with every iteration?

Comment: Now it generates a random string filename.

Comment: And also added a solution for naming the files with increasing numbers

Answer (score 0):

try using `random.choice()`

```py
import random
# your code
word = []
for x in range(0, 7)
    word.add(random.choice(words))
file.write(word)
```

repeat everything after `word = []` using a for loop and you can even check if theyre the same using a method described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_howto_remove_duplicates.asp)